# ReactJS - setState method issue

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am facing one issue with reactjs setState method.
I am using socket io for data communication between client and server.In client UI I am displaying list of faults information. This each fault information will come from socket channel and am taking that information and updating my faults array.
**Problem**: Suppose 10 faults is coming at a time, 10 times I need to listen the socket and 10 times I need to update my setState method for updating my faults array.
this faults array is not updating until complete listening 10 faults.
So here setState is going to queue, not updating immediately. That time my window is going to hang to avoid this what I have to do and how to over come this problem.

**My code snippet:**

```
this.faultsSocket.on('fault', fault => {
    let coreFault = fault   
    let encryptedString = coreFault._str
    let encryptedStringArray = encryptedString.split(' ')
    let decryptedStringArray = []
    for (let value of encryptedStringArray) {
        if (value in description) {
            decryptedStringArray.push(description[value])
        }
    }
    coreFault._desc = decryptedStringArray.length > 0 ? decryptedStringArray.join(' ') : encryptedString    
    let faults = this.state.backupFaults
    let index = faults.findIndex(item => item._num === coreFault._num && item._obj === coreFault._obj)
    if (index > -1) {
        faults = [
            coreFault,
            ...faults.slice(0, index),
            ...faults.slice(index + 1)
        ]
    } else {
        faults = [coreFault, ...faults]
    }
    this.setState({
        faults: faults,
        backupFaults: faults
    });
})
```

Comment: Can you please add sample code of the place where you use `setState` and describe what goes wrong?

Comment: Edit the question please

Comment: @cbll added code please check it.

Comment: If you want `setState` to be triggered in each index, you need it in the for loop

Comment: setState has to trigger when new fault came through socket. If 10 faults coming one by one 10 times this code will execute and 10 times my setState method will call and that time my window is hanging for some time.